# Oracle - copy table from one schema to another using ant

Tags: oracle, ant

I need to copy a table from one oracle schema to another, I can do this by running the following query in schema_one -

```
create table EMPLOYEES unrecoverable as select * from schema_two.EMPLOYEES;
```

which works when run using the command line or sql developer.

But the challenge is to execute this using ant script.

I have my ant target as below

```
<target name="create.tables">
        <echo message="creating tables... " />
        <sql driver="${db.driver}"  
             url="${db.url}"
             userid="${db.username}"
             password="${db.password}"
             onerror="abort"
             keepformat="yes"
             encoding="UTF-8"
            >
            <transaction>
                create table EMPLOYEES unrecoverable as select * from schema_two.EMPLOYEES;

            </transaction>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="database.common.classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </sql>
    </target>
```

where db.driver,db.url,db.username and db.password are defined for schema_one. 
Running this throws an error as below

I have an entry in tnsnames.ora for the schemas as well.

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:825)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:751)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:38)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:366)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:963)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:628)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:857)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:287)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:113)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolStream.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolStream.java:324)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1963)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:564)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: THen your connect string is not being constructed correctly. Are you sure all the properties being referenced are valid?

Comment: Yes they do, if I run a simple query on without schema_two reference ,it runs perfectly fine!

Comment: can you re-try using `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myorcldbservicename)))` as `db.url`. don't forget to change `myhost` and `myorcldbservicename`.